# Strange behavior when using QuickCheck and Debug.Trace in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am getting a strange behavior when using QuickCheck and Debug.Trace in Haskell. I have the code below, which defines a type `S` and makes it an instance of the Arbitrary typeclass. In the middle of the implementation of `arbitrary` I use `Debug.Trace.trace` to track what is going on.

```
data S = C Float | R Float Float | T Float Float Float deriving Show
instance Arbitrary S where
  arbitrary = do
    x <- return () -- STRANGE: Without this line, the string "aaa" is only
                   --          shown for the first occurrence of a C value.
                   --          But with it, the string "aaa" is show for 
                   --          every arbitrary value of a C value.
    aaa <- Debug.Trace.trace "aaa" $ choose (0.0, 10.0)
    bbb <- Debug.Trace.trace "bbb" $ choose (0.0, 10.0)
    ccc <- choose (0.0, 10.0)
    ddd <- choose (0.0, 10.0)
    eee <- choose (0.0, 10.0)
    fff <- Debug.Trace.trace "fff" $ choose (0.0, 10.0)
    elements [C aaa,
              R bbb ccc,
              T ddd eee fff]
prop_s (C x) = True
prop_s (R x y) = True
prop_s (T x y z) = True
p = verboseCheckWith stdArgs {maxSuccess = 10 } prop_s
```

The strange thing is that the previous code behaves differently with and without the line `x <- return ()`, which at first seems irrelevant, when evaluating `p` in GHCi.

What is the sense of this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Debug.trace uses `unsafePerformIO`, so the answer to the question "why do the semantics of Debug.trace appear to be so inconsistent" is "because it uses unsafePerformIO". I'm not that there is any deeper meaning to this.

Comment: @user2407038 Is there any other way to do what I want with the "trace" that does not have these kind of problems? Also, what is the way to have trace-like code turned off/on without having to change the source code?

Comment: Trace is intended only for debugging, it is perfectly acceptable to use trace as you are doing so and then remove it in final code. You can use CPP or cabal conditionals or the like to have trace "enabled" conditionally on different compiles, but it probably isn't worth it.. simpler to define `trace _ x = x` in your file and comment out `import Debug.Trace` when you are ready to get rid of it.